# Que veut-on dire par "goudronnait leurs manchettes" dans Cendrillon?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, expressions, habillement

Dans Cendrillon, on peut lire, dans le passage suivant, "goudronnait leurs manchettes". J'ai beau regarder dans plusieurs dictionnaires, tous semblent s'entendre pour dire qu'on parle d'appliquer du goudron. Existe-t-il une autre définition ou parle-t-on vraiment d'appliquer du goudron sur les manches?

> Il arriva que le fils du roi donna un bal et qu'il en pria toutes les
>   personnes de qualité. Nos deux demoiselles en furent aussi priées, car
>   elles faisaient grande figure dans le pays.  Les voilà bien aises et
>   bien occupées à choisir les habits et les coiffures qui leur siéraient
>   le mieux. Nouvelle peine pour Cendrillon, car c'était elle qui
>   repassait le linge de ses sœurs et qui **goudronnait leurs manchettes**.
>   On ne parlait que de la manière dont on s'habillerait. "Moi", dit
>   l'aînée, "Je mettrai mon habit de velours rouge et ma garniture
>   d'Angleterre." "Moi", dit la cadette, "Je n'aurai que ma jupe
>   ordinaire ; mais, en récompense, je mettrai mon manteau à fleurs d'or
>   et ma barrière de diamants, qui n'est pas des plus indifférentes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

D'après le [dictionnaire de la langue française](http://books.google.fr/books?id=fLVKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=goudronner%20les%20manchettes&source=bl&ots=LWw_teNqyV&sig=_nvGC_CDvMOMn4Afvtv3FYTWb00&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=aKaqT6vFOca90QW296WJBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=goudronner%20les%20manchettes&f=false) il s'agit d'un terme de blanchisserie qui désigne l'action de faire des petits plis avec la main le long de la manchette.

Il s'agit d'une autre écriture de *godronner* comme expliqué dans le 
[Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue française](http://books.google.fr/books?id=atcSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=goudronner%20les%20manchettes&source=bl&ots=JicMJ8TqQg&sig=ryDwsg7m4nRAbRQaghzvqWJR6TA&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=aKaqT6vFOca90QW296WJBA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=goudronner%20les%20manchettes&f=false)

> De ce que le goudron sert à rendre les bâtiments et les cordages plus
>   fermes, plus solides, on a fait : 
>   GODRONNER : empeser [...] des manchettes et par métaplasme, orner de godrons.  
>   GODRONS : plis ronds aux manchettes.

Answer (score 11):

Ah ben non, ça serait dégoûtant…

Goudronner des manchettes vient en fait du terme **godronner** des manchettes. Ce n'est cependant pas une faute de frappe car les deux termes peuvent être employés dans ce contexte et signifient la même chose.

Extrait du *[Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue françoise, où les mots sont classés par familles](http://books.google.ch/books?id=atcSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=goudronner+des+manchettes&source=bl&ots=JicMJ8TmKb&sig=1z0YbyoWJFRFl34jjI5eh9HTxW8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mKSqT7LID8qQ-wbB59ygCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=goudronner%20des%20manchettes&f=false)* de *Jean-Baptiste-Bonaventure de Roquefort-Flaméricourt, Champolliont-Figeac* :

> GODRONNER, empeser une fraise, un jabot, des manchettes, et par métaplasme, orner de godrons.
>   GODRON, plis ronds aux manchettes ; rayon au fond d'une bague ; ornement d'architecture qui ressemble à une amande alongée. (...)

NOTE : « alongée » semblait ne prendre qu'un seul « l » à l'époque.

Answer (score 3):

Goudronner en vieux français : « terme de blanchisseur et menu linge, qui se dit en parlant de manchettes, et c'est faire de petits plis avec la main le long de la manchette lorsqu'elle est empesée ».

Confirmation du lien fourni par Cédric Julien et Otarus dans :

- Le *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue françoise*, où les mots sont classés par familles : contenant les mots du Dictionnaire de l'Académie Françoise, avec les principaux termes d'arts, de sciences et de métiers. Précédé d'une dissertation sur l'étymologie, Volume 1 (Livre numérique Google)
  [[lien](http://books.google.be/books?id=atcSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=goudronner%20manchette&source=bl&ots=JicMK8QjJc&sig=RSvpKVnySeSf74phcybvVTS6lKM&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Sx6sT-38JYK1hAe9tdCMAg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=goudronner%20manchette&f=false)]

et

- Le *Dictionnaire de la langue françoise, ancienne et moderne* :
  E - O, Volume 2 (Livre numérique Google)
  [[lien](http://books.google.be/books?id=fLVKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=goudronner%20manchette&source=bl&ots=LWw_ueKjrR&sig=8BWsVEIxSB3GAtUEC3_fa8S-PGo&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Sx6sT-38JYK1hAe9tdCMAg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=goudronner%20manchette&f=false)]

Et merci pour cette question, j'ai appris quelque chose d'inhabituel. :)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas en quoi ça aide de donner les mêmes liens que Cédric et Oltarus ?

Comment: De poster ce que j'ai trouvé et lu; et de dire que j'ai apprécié la question.
Je ne voulais offenser personne. Je m'en excuse si c'est le cas.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois qu'on parle ici d'une substance différente du goudron de pétrole (on produit du goudron à partir de certaines plantes aussi). On goudronnait les tissus, notamment les toiles sur les navires ou les chapeaux (on trouve souvent des références à des chapeaux goudronnés), mais je ne suis pas certain s'il s'agissait de les rigidifier (comme l'amidon) ou de les imperméabiliser. Bref, je ne suis pas certain du pourquoi et du comment de l'opération, mais elle ne semble pas entièrement hors de propos.

Comment: Effectivement, dans la marine à voile, la toile goudronnée servait à protéger de la pluie ou des embruns le gréement ou les parties du pont qui n'étaient pas des passages. Exemple : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/taud. On n'a aucun moyen de savoir si Cendrillon avait le pied marin, mais il est difficile d'imaginer qu'elle imperméabilise des manchettes pour une réception.